# How to get the source code of installed APKs by accessing the ADB. Is it even possible?

Tags: android, adb

I want to get the source code of one of the APKs installed on my customized android device. I do have ADB root access, is it possible to get the source code of the particular APK installed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Source code? Have you looked to see if the APK files are supposed to have the source code? I assume their compiled, which would mean there isn't source code in the published product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the source code. Neither APKs nor the more modern AABs contain source code.